# Cortar imagem dentro de uma div em CSS

Tags: php, css, css3

Preciso que qualquer tamanho de imagem fique centralizado dentro da div:

Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com isso de código css para fazer o circulo da imagem:

```
.anuncio_dialogo {
    background-color: #FFF; 
    width: 128px; 
    height:128px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Para fazer o círculo estou usando outra classe CSS

```
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

Para chamar na view estou utilizando:

```
<img src="<?=base_url() . $anuncio->imagemPrincipal?>" class="anuncio_dialogo circle">
```

Exemplo de como tudo está atualmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a primeira imagem está distorcida pois ela é maior na largura, sendo que as outras são um quadrado perfeito.

Comment: A classe na imagem ali, esta certo? você colocou "circle", mas no css colocou "img-circle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito ter algumas formas de resolver isso, uma delas seria a usa div ter um `position: relative` e um `position: absolute` na imagem, ai vc centraliza utilizando `margin` e `top`

Ex:

```
<div class="container-image">
   <img src="source-image.jpg" class="centralize-image" />
</div>
```

Ai no css:

```
.container-image{  
    width: 128px;   
    height: 128px;   
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.centralize-image{  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;  
    margin-top: -(ALTURA-IMAGEM / 2)px;  
    margin-left: -(LARGURA-IMAGEM /2)px;  
}
```

Veja o exemplo acima [funcionando no JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5wc7v7vx/)

Ou utilizar a imagem como background no css ex:

```
<div class="container-image"></div>


.container-image{  
    width: 128px;   
    height: 128px;   
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden; 
    background: url(source-image.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
}
```

Veja o exemplo acima [funcionando no JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fqanL68h/)

Se for pensar bem tem muitas outras formas, com essas duas acho que já fica mais tranquilo pra você ter umas ideias do que fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `background-image` junto com `background-size` para ajustar a imagem [Alterando a escala das imagens de background](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images)